# How does React parent component get selected date from react-day-picker

Tags: react-day-picker

Here is their sample component.

```
class MyAwesomeComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedDay: new Date(),
  };
  handleDayClick = day => {
    this.setState({
      selectedDay: day,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DayPicker
          onDayClick={this.handleDayClick}
          selectedDays={this.state.selectedDay}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How do you get the selected data from this sample react component?

Answer (score 1):

`this.state.selectedDay` will have your selected date after the selection complete.

Comment: this.state.selectedDay is in the context of DayPicker not my parent component.  I don't have access to DayPicker's state.

Comment: on `handleDayClick = (day) => {...} ` you are setting the selected day to your states selectedDay.

Comment: this.state.selectedDay is undefined in parent component.  My solution was to pass a callback function into the component and return the value through the callback.

Comment: then I think this is not your actual code. Can you paste your actual code please